# IOS MKMapView sidewalk

Tags: ios, mapkit

Im working with `Mapkit` and I trying to draw a line in the "sidewalks" (border of the street),right now I'm looking for ideas on how I could start this task, thanks for your help.

notes: I know how to works with mkpolyline and coordinates

http://s30.postimg.org/7rnmdjzu9/mapa.png

Comment: How about a bit more information on what exactly you've attempted so far. That will get you more help!

Comment: I have to draw a line on the edge of a block, I working with a MKmapview, I'm looking for a function or lib that returns me the segment or something to give me the coordinates of the segment to paint.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to the information that qualifies as a road inside the MKMapView. so, in order to be able to draw into the border of the street you will need to access the information that qualifies as a street (the coordinates of the road) or analyzing the view and changing the specific color represented by the border of the street (this is not public API, you will need to dig around the view hierarchy).